# AWS-SDK Undefined Method presigned_post

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

A friend has a project that i'm looking to, to be able to upload a video directly to s3. All the code, all the aws gems, and configurations are the same. My codebase says that presigned_post isn't a method on the bucket object - The S3_BUCKET is defined.

[image: Here is where i'm making my call to set the presignedPost]

[image: This is my configurations where the S3_BUCKET is set]

Does anyone know why my S3_BUCKET object simply doesn't have the presigned_post method? It has to be somewhere in configurations or gems i'm thinking but i feel like i've tried everything.

GEM LIST:
aws-sdk (2.8.11, 2.0.6.pre)
aws-sdk-core (2.8.11, 2.0.6)
aws-sdk-resources (2.8.11, 2.0.6.pre)
aws-sdk-v1 (1.66.0)
aws-sigv4 (1.0.0)
fog-aws (0.9.4, 0.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

By updating the gemfile to explicitly say gem 'aws-sdk', '>= 2.6.1' i was able to solve the problem